# $\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{x+4}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{x+4}dx$$

I have evaluated this integral by splitting at -$\infty$ and -4 for one integral and -4 to 0 for the other. However, my teacher put a note saying I need 3 integrals, because both $-\infty$ and -4 are discontinuous in the integral. Symbolab show 2 splits as well. Which is correct?

Comment: @Arthur is is the first one, and yes i mean to include dx

Comment: Symbolab is correct (the second one)

Comment: @TheDeadLegend How come I dont need to split it 3 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would kind of agree with your teacher, saying you need three definite integrals:

$$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac1{x+4}dx=\lim_{x_0\rightarrow-\infty}\int_{x_0}^{-5}\frac1{x+4}dx+
\lim_{x_1\rightarrow-4}\int_{-5}^{x_1}\frac1{x+4}dx
+ \lim_{x_2\rightarrow-4}\int_{x_2}^{0}\frac1{x+4}dx$$

Each of these integrals is definite. When you split only into two you have one integral, that needs a limit process onboth borders, which can turn out to be a bad thing.

Comment: Yes, thats how she showed me in class. How come symbolab still shows that you can split it twice? Should I just always stick to only having one discontinuity per limit?

Comment: Essentially yes, however, as soon as you get comfortable with these kind of integral it's "fine" to don't follow the rules that strictly anymore. Just be aware, that the original integral is only defined, if each of these limits actually exist. If they do exist, then you can strechen the rules a bit.

Comment: So how do I solve for a discontinuity on top and on bottom? Do I evaluate with 2 limits on 1 integral?

Comment: For example: I work in biology, we just assume, that everything we write down does converge. So for computing $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ I just compute the antiderivative and plug in: $\int_a^bf(x)dx = F(b)-F(a)$. However this is a very cruel way, so don't do this if you're still working in pure mathematics/studying (which I guess you are both). When you know, that the limits converge uniformly, then this method will work.

Comment: When I evaluate it I am left with -$\infty$ + $\infty$. isnt that an indeterminate?

Comment: Yes, in this specific case the limits 2 and 3 do not converge. That is correct.

Comment: Oh so you dont really add them together, as long as one of them isn't convergent you can assume that there is no possibility for convergence correct?

Comment: Essentially this is not a problem of integrals anymore, but becomes a problem of limits. You are allowed to add two limits, if both are converging. If one of them is not converging you can't add them. Typically one adds the rule, that if one "converges" to $\infty$ we can still add a converging with one that "converges" to $\infty$. If two converge to the "same" infinity it's fine to add them as well. However in your case we cannot add them, as we do not know what $\infty-\infty$ is.